# Search through ArrayList for value then copy value & key to new TreeSet

Tags: java, arraylist, treeset

So i have an ArrayList of fighters, within this arraylist it holds Fighter objects that have variables as below:

```
public Fighter()
{
  super();
  this.name = "";
  this.ageGroup = "standard";
  this.time = 0;
  this.number = this.nextNumber;
  this.nextNumber++;

}
```

What i'd like to do is search through this arraylsit for anyone who has an ageGroup of standard and then add them to a TreeSet. basically to provide a set of results for say senior age group or junior age group etc. The reason i'm using TreeSet is that the list must have the key's sorted at all times.

these are the lists i'd like to populate:

```
  juniorResults = new TreeSet<>(); 
  standardResults = new TreeSet<>(); 
  seniorResults = new TreeSet<>();
```

So i've got this far:

```
public void categorise(){
  Iterator iter = fighters.iterator();
  while (iter.hasNext()){
     if(runners.contains(Runner.getAgeGroup("senior"))){
        Runner.getAgeGroup("senior");
     }
  }
```

if i'm honest i'm pretty lost on this one so any help / teaching points would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to do the following:

```
public void categorise() {
    for (Fighter fighter : fighters) {
        switch (fighter.getAgeGroup()) {
            case "senior":
                seniorResults.add(fighter);
                break;
            case "standard":
                standardResults.add(fighter);
                break;
            case "junior":
                juniorResults.add(fighter);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

For this to work properly, your `Fighter` class should have a method (preferably abstract) that returns their age group as a `String`, `Fighter#getAgeGroup`.

Comment: it works but for some reason it's missing out 2 of my fighters at index[4] and index [13] any idea why?

Comment: What age group do those fighters have?

Comment: they have "standard"

Comment: How strange, i solved it by placing the standard switch at the top :/

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting.  I was about to post a large comment explaining that there might be duplicates, but I'm glad you fixed it.